# Disable touch events on underlying views while DialogFragment is showing up

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a PreferenceFragment, and while I setup everything needed, I show a DialogFragment signaling loading progress. The problem is that if I click on the preference elements in the underlying fragment, click events are still being processed.

Is there a way to disable events while my DialogFragment is displayed?

My DialogFragment is built and launched from within the PreferenceFragment itself:

```
 final DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment() {
                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_hide_user_title)
                            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_hide_user_summary)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_hide_user_confirm_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int i) {
                                    callback.onPositiveClick();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int i) {
                                    callback.onNegativeClick();
                                }
                            })
                            .create();
                    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    return dialog;
                }
            };
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "test");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Hope this helps :)

Full code :

```
final DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment() {
                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_hide_user_title)
                            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_hide_user_summary)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_hide_user_confirm_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int i) {
                                    callback.onPositiveClick();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int i) {
                                    callback.onNegativeClick();
                                }
                            })
                            .create();
                    setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    return dialog;
                }
            };
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "test");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It still launches whatever is defined in the onClick handler of the underlying preferences

Comment: I edited my answer. I just tested your code with setCancelable(false). It works fine for me. I hope it will work. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set your base layout view to be clickable:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this in my main activity and it worked

```
 private void myDy() {
     FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     TimerDialogFrag dialog = new TimerDialogFrag();
      dialog.setCancelable(false);
     dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
}
```